# NoClassDefFoundErrorについて

Tags: android

MultipartEntityBuilderを用いてAndroidから画像のアップロードを行いたいと思い開発しております。

そんな中NoClassDefFoundErrorが中々消えてくれません。
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder

何かご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただきたいです。

以下自分で試したこと
・libsファイルを作成し中に外部jarを追加（下の位置です）
AplicationName
-src
-gen
中略
-libs
-res

・外部jarのビルドパス構成

使用している外部jar
・httpcore-4.4.2.jar
・httpmime-4.5.jar

```
public class HttpThread extends Thread{
String muri = null;
public HttpThread(String guri){
    muri = guri;
    }

public void run() {
    /*▼▼▼BlobKey取得用▼▼▼*/
    String url = "http://xxxx.appspot.com/bandroid";
    String bkey = "";
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        bkey = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    /*▲▲▲ここまで▲▲▲*/

    /*▼▼▼ＧＡＥアクセス用▼▼▼*/
    try {
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        if(bkey != null) {
            bkey = bkey.substring(0, bkey.length()-1);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(bkey);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Log.v("test", "path=" + muri);
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            File file = new File(muri);
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

            builder.addPart("myFile", fileBody);
            httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());
            httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*▲▲▲ここまで▲▲▲*/
}
```

}

Comment: 開発環境はEclipseですか？

Comment: はい、Lunaを使っています。